# Why does my Loop work in a sub optimal way?

Tags: c

The code works but its weird , when i run it and give the quantity 375 this is the result:

Quantity: 375
2 notes of 100
2 notes of 50
2 notes of 20
2 notes of 10
2 notes of 5
2 notes of 2
1 notes of 1

It should give me 3 notes of 100 , one note of 50 , one note of 20 and one note of 5.
Im really new to coding so this might be really easy.

```
int main(void)

{
    int quantity = get_int("Quantity: ");
    int hundred = 0;
    int fifty = 0;
    int twenty = 0;
    int ten = 0;
    int five = 0;
    int two = 0;
    int one = 0;
    
    
    while ( quantity > 0 )
    
    {
        if ( quantity >= 100 )
        {
            quantity -= 100; 
            hundred++;
        }
        if ( quantity >= 50 )
        {
            quantity -= 50;
            fifty++;
        }
        if ( quantity >= 20 )
        {
            quantity -= 20;
            twenty++;
        }
        if ( quantity >= 10 )
        {
            quantity -= 10;
            ten++;
        }
        if ( quantity >= 5)
        {
            quantity -= 5;
            five++;
        }
        if ( quantity >= 2)
        {
            quantity -= 2;
            two++;
        }
        if ( quantity >= 1 )
        {
            quantity -= 1;
            one++;
        }
    }
    
    printf("%d notes of 100\n", hundred);
    printf("%d notes of 50\n", fifty);
    printf("%d notes of 20\n", twenty);
    printf("%d notes of 10\n", ten);
    printf("%d notes of 5\n", five);
    printf("%d notes of 2\n", two);
    printf("%d notes of 1\n", one);
```

Comment: Use `else if` for all the additional conditions. Otherwise you're testing `quantity` after it has been reduced by the previous `if`.

Comment: But there's no need for a loop. You can just divide `quantity` by the note value to get the number of notes, and then get the remainder before going to the next smaller note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well no lie it's quite ugly to do it like that but well..if it works :)
here is how you can do it:

```
int main(void)

{
     int quantity;
     scanf("%d", &quantity);
int hundred = 0;
int fifty = 0;
int twenty = 0;
int ten = 0;
int five = 0;
int two = 0;
int one = 0;


while ( quantity >= 100 )
{
    quantity -= 100; 
    hundred++;
}
while ( quantity >= 50 )
{
    quantity -= 50;
    fifty++;
}
while ( quantity >= 20 )
{
    quantity -= 20;
    twenty++;
}
while ( quantity >= 10 )
{
    quantity -= 10;
    ten++;
}
while ( quantity >= 5)
{
    quantity -= 5;
    five++;
}
while ( quantity >= 2)
{
    quantity -= 2;
    two++;
}
while ( quantity >= 1 )
{
    quantity -= 1;
    one++;
}

printf("%d notes of 100\n", hundred);
printf("%d notes of 50\n", fifty);
printf("%d notes of 20\n", twenty);
printf("%d notes of 10\n", ten);
printf("%d notes of 5\n", five);
printf("%d notes of 2\n", two);
printf("%d notes of 1\n", one);
}
```

Comment: When posting an entire program, it is easier for other people to test your program if you add all necessary `#include` directives. Also, your program would be easier to read if it had consistent [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if you can remove a 100, then checking if you can remove a 50, etc, and then start all over again. That's not correct.

You want to subtract 100s until you can't. Only THEN you want to subtract 50s until you can't.

```c
while ( quantity >= 100 ) { quantity -= 100; hundred++; }
while ( quantity >=  50 ) { quantity -=  50; fifty++;   }
...
```

---

A better way of achieving the same thing is to use modulus.

```c
hundred = quantity / 100;  quantity = quantity % 100;
fifty   = quantity /  50;  quantity = quantity %  50;
...
```

---

The next step would be to use array of values.

```c
int bills[] = { 100, 50, ... };
const size_t NUM_BILLS = sizeof(bills) / sizeof(bills[0]);

int counts[NUM_BILLS] = { 0 };
```

But coding this version is left to you :)